# How to track CVS Check-Ins

Tags: cvs, wincvs

We recently created a branch out of the main branch of our code for the beta.

Now I want to check what all files have changed in the branch in the last one week. How to get that information out of CVS.

What is the command for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the command line:

```
cvs log -r BRANCHNAME
```

Do do it for a certain date-range:

```
cvs log -r BRANCHNAME -d "1972-09-24"
```

Where `1972-09-24` is actually your date you'd like to get items newer than.

Comment: Thanks XYLD, can I add the date parameter from yesterday to the last 8 days ??