# Where is the CVS log file stored?

Tags: eclipse, version-control, cvs, wincvs

I am using winCVS and I want to access the log file for commits in a repository so That I can search for a certain comment but i cant find the log file anywhere.

Where is it stored?

Answer (score -1):

You could also use the cvs command directly, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2781096/6309):

```
cvs log -r BRANCHNAME | grep acomment
```

(you have grep command on Windows through [Gow Gnu On Windows](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki))

Comment: @codefish578841441 you need to execute that command in your local  working copy.